# A proper use of the Cragg-Donald F-Statistic with more than one endogenous variable

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, f-test, 2sls

I've read that the Cragg-Donald F-Statistic is similar to an F-test on the first-stage OLS regression when you have one endogenous variable. But with more than two endogenous variables, you should use Cragg-Donald's test estimation (while the i.i.d. assumption of the errors holds). But if on the other hand, I am estimating a system of equations on the first-stage in a different way, i.e. one equation for each endogenous variable, would an F-test for each equation suffice or there is something more accurate?